# Reference Excel sheet with apostrophe in name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a large workbook with company names for each sheet. On some of the data sheets, I need to reference the other sheets. In doing so, I would start with an `=sum(` in the formula bar, then click on the cells in the pages I want. Easy so far, right?

Now, how about when I have a very long formula where I am just auto-filling, then changing the sheet name? How can I reference a sheet with an apostrophe (`'`) in it's name?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/107468), you can use a double-apostrophe (`''`) in the name.

For example, `=sum('My Employee's income'!A1:A2)` would become `=sum('My Employee''s income'!A1:A2)`.

Comment: For the record, the same applies for double quotes, i.e. you escape double quotes by doubling them, so `=LEN("""")` equals 1

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know that! I'm also just surprised I haven't seen this question on SU